# database for record system log or history

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-3

first I have to say sorry that i could not know the correct whether it call system log or system history .

I am going to implement a web system which need to fill up various form, I plan to come out a table to record all the single step like insert, update, delete including with old data and new data.

I did some research, but could not get a clear mind. Hope some one can give me a guide. Thank you.

Below are my table structure.

**systemlog**

```
Id (Pk)
editedby (int)
Module (var)
oldValue(text) 
newValue(text)
changeon(datetime)
```

let say all input is

```
Array
(
    [column1] => male
    [column2] => beach
)
```

I plan to use php serialize to save all the form in database.

My problem

1. serialize is the good solution for save all the data ?
2. This db structure enough for recovery data?
3. Any suggestion

** I am using php laravel framework and mysql.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach looks ok to me. Your systemlog table might become large and have lots of writes into it. You should take care that you choose a non-blocking engine like InnoDB, eventually even the [archive engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/archive-storage-engine.html).

In a schema free database like ArangoDB you would not need to serialize the data but simply keep copies of the different versions, I don't have a better idea for MySQL than serialized data like you lined it out.

Comment: Jamie thank for your comment. Sorry, i am new to database as i only experience with mysql. Could give me suggest, is it better to use db like arangodb or mongodb ? As my db might not high frequency use, but important data save.

Comment: From my opinion schema free databases are nice for developing, so have a look if you have some time to learn something new. But going on with MySQL in your case is absolutely ok, as your serialized data is only used for backup purposes, it's not the heart of the application.

Comment: Jamie, thank you! I am appreciate your kindest answer and suggestion. I will take some time for schema free database .

Comment: @Raywin if my answer was helpful, consider accepting it as help for other users who come across this question :-) Thnx.

Comment: Just to add to this, regarding serialized data. If you take the previous dataset and the current updated dataset, you can diff the two arrays. You only need to store the diff in the db to see the changes from create to edit to edit to edit, etc